# How to count the number of elements (<ul>) in a HTML string using Ruby RegEx

Tags: html, ruby, regex

If you had a HTML string in ruby, does anyone know the RegEx I would use to count the number of  tags in that string? This is just a string in the rails database. Many thanks

Comment: Does the answer solved your problem? If so, accept the answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.scan(/<ul>/).count
```

where `string` contains your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Given `s` your string

```
s.scan(/<ul>/).count
```